# Gimp Ellipse Select Tool resizing using Ctrl+Shift stopped working properly

Tags: gimp, selections

Resizing Ellipse Select Tool using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or just using <kbd>Shift</kbd> have suddenly stopped working. Resize with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> still works but is useless since I cannot get a perfect circle anymore. When I resize and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it all of a sudden turns into a small selection area that does not move at all with the cursor marked in red (cursor cannot be screenshot)

[image]

Everything still works for the rectangle select tool though. Here an animation. Notice that whenever I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the ellipse selection freezes as a small circle that doesn't move:

[image]

Here's what happens when I first do a <kbd>LMB</kbd> and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>. It works properly for rectangle select but it drags the circle select around. But if I drag first and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it turns into a small circle which is frozen and doesn't move. I think this is a bug. It was still working with the same document today and then suddenly started behaving like this.

[image]

Is this a bug? Closing the Gimp software and opening again did not resolve the problem, neither did creating a new document.

Comment: Hmm.  Try holding down Shift+Ctrl after you begin dragging one of the handles, don't press them first. I can't really tell what is going on here so this is only a guess.

Comment: I've done [a screnshot](https://imgur.com/JpkcF7c) showing how the Expand from Center option comes on in the tool options when Ctrl is pressed, and the Fixed option when Shift is pressed.

Comment: I also note you have the Tool Options undocked from the tool bar, which isn't a good idea in my opinion. Best to keep it always visible so you can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: I've updated the post to show what happens when I first left click and then press shift and then drag. it works with the rectangle tool but behaves weird with the ellipse tool, it gets dragged around lol i'm using the latest version 2.10.32. if i first drag and then press shift you will see it directly turns into a small circle and stops moving.

Comment: i dont' know how to dock the toolbars. double-clicking it doesn't work. and i can't find anything in the menus.

Comment: Can I suggest you reset the windows to their default settings.  In Edit > Preferences > Interface > Windows Management, select Hint for Docs to **Utility Window**, and hit the **Reset Saved Window Positions to Default Values**.

Comment: @BillyKerr hey thank you for showing the screenshot! I just realized what happened! The "Fixed" option changed to something other than *Aspect Ratio* because of the bad/incorrect usability of the toolbox. Because when I scroll down, I expected it to scroll the window content but instead it scrolls the options depending on where the mouse is hovered over, so I accidentally changed it to something other than *Aspect Ratio*.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you need to have the tool options visible at all times. Otherwise you will not see what is going on. GIMP is a complex tool and because of that, there are many custom ways to adjust the operation of the tools via the controls.

Comment: The problem is I cannot get them visible all the time. I can't dock them. They always float around and disappear from time to time. I have logged a question on it here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159493/gimp-2-10-32-toolbox-docking-doesnt-work-on-windows-7