# Gimp 2.10.32 Toolbox Docking doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: gimp, tools, user-experience

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr3aQYdl0p4) on how to dock the toolbar options but it doesn't work for me on Windows 7. I'm using 2.10.32. Nothing happens when I drag the Tool Options into the Toolbox. I also cannot dock the Toobox on the left side. They all float around. How do I get them all docked automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

1. From the main menu, go to *Windows* and select Single Window Mode, if not already selected.

[image]

2. From the main menu, go to *Edit > Preferences*
3. Expand the *Interface* options, and click on *Window Management*
4. Set **Utility window** in the Hint for docks and toolbox
5. Hit the **Reset Saved Window Positions to Default Values**

[image]

6. And finally: Quit and Restart GIMP.

Also note that if you accidentally detach an item from its dock, you need to click and drag the tab, not the Window itself. You should see the dock light up in blue, then you can drop it there.

[image]

Comment: awesome! thank you very much!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Excellent, glad it's fixed for you now!

Comment: `Tool options` can detach itself almost spontaneously. You can lock it down (click the `|<|` icon to the right of the tabs, and select `Lock tab to dock`).

Comment: @xenoid - yeah, forgot about that. Great idea. Lock it down!!!